Daily Pattern Clustering Methods for Time Series Data
I’m working on a project involving daily usage patterns of GN2 (Nitrogen Gas). My primary goal is to reduce the variance of daily patterns and minimize the gap between GN2 production and consumption by analyzing patterns more effectively. Here’s a brief overview of my approach and the challenges I’m facing:
Data: I have GN2 usage data recorded at 10-minute intervals for over a year. Each day’s pattern is represented as a time series with around 144 data points.
Objective: The key objective is to reduce the variance between daily usage patterns and create representative patterns that can help in aligning production output to meet the actual usage more closely.
Current Approach:
DTW-based Clustering: I am using Dynamic Time Warping (DTW) to cluster daily patterns and understand the inherent structure of different usage profiles.
I’m also considering external variables like temperature and humidity, as they seem to influence the GN2 consumption.
After clustering, I analyze each cluster’s patterns in terms of daily usage variance, production-consumption gaps, and external factors.
Challenges:

Variance Reduction: Even after clustering, I’m observing that the variance within each cluster is still relatively high, making it hard to define a clear, stable representative pattern.
Weekday vs. Weekend Patterns: I tried incorporating weekday/weekend and monthly seasonality differences into the clustering process, but there’s no significant difference in patterns.
Balancing Production and Usage: My ultimate goal is to use these patterns to help adjust production output according to the predicted daily usage. However, the remaining variance is still making this prediction difficult.

Questions:

How can I further reduce the variance within each cluster’s daily pattern? Are there any advanced techniques I should try (e.g., using Wavelet Transforms, autoencoders, or other time series decomposition methods)?

Would it be better to separate the clustering into weekday/weekend or seasonal clusters and then re-cluster? If so, what criteria should I use to define meaningful clusters?

Any suggestions on incorporating external variables like temperature and humidity more effectively into the clustering process to capture the seasonality and demand changes?


I’m open to any feedback or ideas on how to improve this analysis and make the production-consumption matching more accurate.

(I have solved similar problems in time series for 25 years)
Sometimes you have to get past this paradox.
You should only cluster the items that are clusterable.
If you have even a small number of items that are outliers, they will prevent stable clusters forming.
For some threshold T, I scan thru the dataset and remove any item that is not within T of some neighbour. The is O(n^2) worse case, but with early abandoning, essentially (N).
Then I cluster only the items that pass that test.
The output is something like::
This 87% of the data falls into 4 strong clusters
This 13% of the data is noisy, or corresponds to the hurricane we had, and does not fit into any meaningful cluster other than "undefine/poor data"
